# SAPUI5 Web content widget

Tags: widget, sapui5

So I'm trying to develop a so called "Web Content Widget" to use in the SAP Cloud Portal, as described here: https://help.sap.com/viewer/3ca6847da92847d79b27753d690ac5d5/Cloud/en-US/b3b13c6b75244a18887180353ce49599.html

What I'm trying to create is a title with an icon next to it. Clicking the icon should open a popover with some text.
The title and the popover text should be configurable from the Cloud Portal.

Right now I have a configurable title and configurable text, but how do I implement a mechanism to open and close the popover in that framework?

Is there a way to use event handlers in a "Web Content Widget"?
Or perhaps: Is there a way to use sap.m.popover? 
(i.e. Transforming a SAPUI5 app in a portal widget and adding options? But how?)

Edit:

Folder structure looks like this:

- CustomContentWidget

  - ContentUnits

    - popover.json (contains the "settings/configuration" that can be edited in the Portal)
  - renderers

    - popoverRenderer.js
  - snippets

    - popover.html
  - Component.js
  - manifest.json
- cp.app.descriptor.json

The "popoverRenderer.js and "popover.html" snippet:

```js
sap.ui.define([
 "sap/ushell/cpv2/services/control/contentUnit/WebContentRenderer"
], function(WebContentRenderer) {
 "use strict";
 return WebContentRenderer.extend("infoblockpopover.renderers.popoverRenderer", {

  getDefaultSettings: function() {
   var defaultSettings = {
    height: "10rem"
   };
   return defaultSettings;
  },

  onInit: function() {

  },

  onThemeChanged: function() {

  },

  createSettingsEditor: function(propertyEditorManager) {
   var propertyEditor = propertyEditorManager.editor;

   this.addPropertyEditor({
    key: "height",
    category: propertyEditorManager.bundle.getText("WIDGET_CATEGORY_DIMENSIONS"),
    title: propertyEditorManager.bundle.getText("WIDGET_SETTINGS_LABEL_HEIGHT"),
    editor: propertyEditor.Size,
    flags: propertyEditor.Size.AUTO | propertyEditor.Size.UNIT_PX | propertyEditor.Size.UNIT_PT | propertyEditor.Size.UNIT_REM
   });
  },

  renderer: {
   render: function(oRm, oControl) {
    var settings = oControl.getSettings();
    oRm.write("<div");
     oRm.writeClasses();
     oRm.writeControlData(oControl);
    oRm.write(">");
    oRm.write("<div>");
    var uiComps = oControl.getItems();

    jQuery.each(uiComps, function() {
     oRm.write("<div style='position: relative;height:" + settings.height + "'>");
     oRm.renderControl(this);
     oRm.write("<div style='clear: both'></div>");
     oRm.write("</div>");
    });
    oRm.write("</div>");
    oRm.write("</div>");
   }
  }
 });
}, true);
```

```html
<component>
    <style>
        /* Some style here */
    </style>

    <div class="{$dir} {$device}">
        <div class="zBILink ['{popoverText}'?'':'zBILinkHide']" >
            <span class="icon-wl-icon-question onclick-menu" tabindex="0">
                <div class="onclick-menu-content">{popoverText}</div>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</component>
```

Comment: Maybe you should also add which controls you are using.

Comment: Can't you use the press event of the icon?

Comment: I don't know how to do that inside this "Web Content Widget" construct.

A CSS checkbox hack works, but the absolute positioned popover is contained within a generated container with 'overflow: hidden' on it...

I've also been searching for a way to add those edit options ('ContentUnit/popover.json') inside a SAPUI5 project that has been converted to a Portal app. This way you could (theoratically) create an app that is configurable through the Portal website editor. But no luck so far...